# custom filter pipe in ngfor ~ ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a filter to be used in an ngFor loop and am getting an error as well as another issue.

My pipe seems pretty simple. I am passing an argument of an id number to filter by and then comparing that to one of the object properties:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'groupBy'
})

export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(items: any, groupId: number ): any {
        console.log(groupId);
        items.filter(items => items.storyFunnelStatusId === groupId);
    }

}
```

then my template i get the column.id from a previous loop as the argument for the filter:

```
<div class="board-container">
    <div class="board-column" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
        <div class="board-heading">
            {{ column.name }}
            <span class="count">4</span>
        </div>
        <div id="column-{{ column.id }}" class="card-body">
            <div *ngFor="let item of results | groupBy: column.id">
                <pre>{{ item | json }}</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

two issues, first the big one is that i am getting a console error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

the second is that when I try to `console.log('groupId')` I am getting 10 results where i should just be getting one.

Bout to pull my hair out here :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined` indicates that your `items` in `GroupByPipe` is undefined, which means you are passing wrong params to it.

By modifying your template will fix it.

```
<div class="board-container">
    <div class="board-column" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
        <div class="board-heading">
            {{ column.name }}
            <span class="count">4</span>
        </div>
        <div id="column-{{ column.id }}" class="card-body">
            <div *ngFor="let item of (results | groupBy: column.id)">
                <pre>{{ item | json }}</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Because `let item of results` becomes the first param you send to pipe and this expression's value is `undefined`.

---

In the meanwhile you can add some safety checks in the pipe's implementation like this:

```
transform(items: [any], groupId: number ): any {
    console.log(groupId);
    if(items instanceof Array) {
        return items.filter(items => items.storyFunnelStatusId === groupId);
    }
    return [];
}
```

Comment: cool thanks, so this now at least gets the filter working, meaning I can see the data, but I am still getting an undefined error?

Comment: @SandraWillford That's easy. And some `undefine` check can solve it...I'll update the answer.